# Make a function that returns 1 if x < y , otherwise return 0

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Editor's note: This is one quiz from CS:APP Data Lab, where the intention is to teach 2's complement integer representation (so please don't comment about poor C practices). There are extra assumptions and restrictions over ISO C:

- `int` is 32 bits, using 2's complement representation
- Signed integer overflow wraps around (`-fwrapv`)
- Right-shifting is arithmetic on signed types, i.e., the MSB is duplicated to fill in the shifted bits

---

As part of a coding project in my coding class, one that teaches C, we were given a number of bit manipulation questions with restrictions. Seen here:

```
CheckIfLess - if x < y then return 1, else return 0 
 *   Example: CheckIfLess(4,5) = 1.
 *   Legal operations: ! ~ & ^ | + >>
 *   Max ops: 13
 */
```

Besides the legal operations listed, I can't use any statements such as do, if, while, or else. I can't cast to other data types either. Also I can't use any constant bigger than 0xFF, not that I think it'll come up for this problem. Also, assume we are using a 32 bit machine.

Here is my code so far:

```
int CheckIfLess(int x, int y) {
  int xSign, ySign, same, diffSign, ovfTrue, ovfFalse;
  same = !(x ^ y); //1 if same, else 0
  xSign = x >> 31; //get sign of x
  ySign = y >> 31; //get sign of y
  diffSign = (x + ~y + 1) >> 31; //(x - y) then checking if they have a diff sign
  
  
  // These are for overflow cases
  ovfTrue = xSign & ~ySign;
  ovfFalse = xSign | ~ySign;

  return !!((ovfTrue | ~diffSign) & ovfFalse);
}
```

One thing that I know everyone will point out is that the 'same' variable isn't implemented in the answer. This is because I'm not sure were to put it to be honest. Also, I'm already 3 operations over the limit, so I need to cut out some stuff.

Could you explain your answers to me really well, I've only been learning C for just shy of a month. **Also, can you explain how I'd go about reversing the function so that it would return 1 if x > y instead of x < y, else return 0?**

Edit: I can't use -. I'm just supposed to use the legal operations listed in the first code chuck

Edit2: Updated my notes on the code based on what I think each statement does. Changed the x - y statement to actually be x - y instead of y - x.

Edit3: added bolded question at bottom

Comment: Step one, try `return x < y;` and review the emitted code.  See what your compiler does.

Comment: If you subtract x from y, the result will have a sign bit of 1 iff x < y.  I.e., a sign bit of 1 is equivalent to saying the number is negative. You already show how to get the sign bit, so I'm not giving anything away by saying (x - y) >> 31 ought to work.

Comment: FWIW, this is a poor assignment to teach C.  Code like `x >> 31` relies on _implementation-defined behavior_ , `y + ~x + 1)` risks `int` overflow and _undefined behavior_ and overall  encourages poor programming practices.

Comment: OT: There seem to be a number of this "bitwise challenge" questions appearing recently... Was there a sale on some "quiz book" for the new year?

Comment: +1 to poor for C programming practice, but also +1 if the intent is to gain familiarity with 2s complement representations in the early days of learning. The next lesson can be about the dangers of non-portable code. Teaching is successive revelation, where the early revelations often involve oversimplification.   Some teachers call them constructive lies.

Comment: Gene is correct that you want to compute `x - y` and check the sign bit. (The code in the question is computing `y - x`.)  But the results of `x - y` are only valid if `x` and `y` have the same sign.

Comment: I've made some changes to my code now based on what I think you guys are saying. But it still don't know how to implement the 'same' variable, or even if my return statement is working. Plus I have to many operators. I'm only allowed to use 14.

Comment: @Gene unless it overflows.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov unfortunately I'm not allowed to use casting, nor unsigned variables.

Comment: @Josh, how about `!!((x + (~y + 1)) & 0x80000000)`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov  I can't use any constant bigger than 0xFF, so I can't use 0x80000000. I tried to use it in an earlier version of my code and it got flagged as illegal. Do you know any code than is equivalent to 0x80000000?

Comment: @Josh, Hmm. Then you'll probably need to run a loop comparing bits `(x>>i) & 1` and `(y>>i) & 1` from left(MSB) to right. if the former is zero and the latter is one, then the result should be one, with the only exception that you'll also need to handle edge cases such as when both are negative and one is negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` and `y` have different sign bits, then we only have to check if `x` is negative.

Else, we can check if `x-y` is negative

That would be:

```
return (x<0 != y<0) ? (x<0) : (x-y)<0;
```

Let's now rewrite those operations with the ones we have:

```
t < 0       ==>   t >> 31
x-y         ==>   x + ~y + 1
c ? t : f   ==>   c & t | ~c & f  // (c&(t^f))^f (-1 ops)
a != b      ==>   a^b
```

That gives us (13 ops):

```
sign_x = x >> 31;
sign_y = y >> 31;
sign_xy = sign_x ^ sign_y;
x_minus_y = x + ~y + 1;
sign_x_minus_y = x_minus_y >> 31;
x_lt_y = sign_xy & sign_x | ~sign_xy & sign_x_minus_y;
return !!x_lt_y;  // x_lt_y & 1 (-1 ops)
```

We can further simplify (9 ops) by extracting the "`>>31`" operation, that is `a>>31 @ b>>31 == (a @ b)>>31` where `@` is one of `&, |, ^`:

```
xy = x ^ y;
x_y = x + ~y + 1;
x_lt_y = (xy & (x ^ x_y)) ^ x_y;
return (x_lt_y>>31) & 1;
```

All the other comparisons can be obtained as such:

- `x > y`  is `(y < x)`
- `x <= y` is `!(y < x)`
- `x >= y` is `!(x < y)`
- `x == y` is `!(y<x | x<y)`
- `x != y` is `!!(y<x | x<y)`

Comment: When I tested you code I got this error message: "ERROR: Test CheckIfLess(-2147483648[0x80000000],2147483647[0x7fffffff]) failed...
...Gives 1[0x1]. Should be 0[0x0]"

Comment: @Josh But -2147483648 is indeed less than 2147483647

Comment: This can be simplified a lot: `sign_xy = (x ^ y) >> 31; return ((x | sign_xy) - y) >>> 31` (note first shift is arithmetic, second logical), with the same rewrite for the `-`.