# Using only bit manipulations, return a mask that marks the position of the most significant 1 bit. If x == 0, return 0

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

As part of my coding class, an intro to C, I'm working on a coding project dealing with bit manipulation under restrictions. On this question in particular, I'm stuck because I don't know how to fix my error.

```
/* 
 * SigBitMask - return a mask that marks the position of the
 *           most significant 1 bit. If x == 0, return 0
 *   Example: SigBitMask(96) = 0x40
 *   Legal operations: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *   Max operations: 16
 *   Rating: 4 
 */
```

Besides the legal operations listed, I can't use any statements such as do, if, while, or else. I'm not allowed cast to other data types either., this includes using unsigned. **Also I can't use any constant bigger than 0xFF, which is super important for this problem since I'm not allowed to use 0x80000000.** Also, assume we are using a 32 bit machine.

A big thing here is that I **can't** use operations like - or * which would make this a lot easier.

Here is my code so far:

```
int SigBitMask(int x) {
  x |= x >> 1;
  x |= x >> 2;
  x |= x >> 4;
  x |= x >> 8;
  x |= x >> 16;
  x = x ^ (x >> 1);
  return x & ~(x >> 1);
}
```

The error the checking software is giving me says:

```
    "ERROR: Test SigBitMask(-2147483648[0x80000000]) failed...
    ...Gives 0[0x0]. Should be -2147483648[0x80000000]
```

I'm not quiet sure how to go about fixing my problem. I'd prefer more than just the answer. Can someone actually explain the process too. The whole point of this project is to learn to code in C. Thanks :)

Edit: I know there is a similar problem on Stack Overflow already, but their restrictions were different than mine, plus I'm looking for help fixing my code, and understanding why.

Edit2: Clarified what max and legal ops meant

Comment: Well let's just think about the simple case of `x == -1`.  Since you are using a signed type, `-1 >> N` is always -1.  What can we do to return the right answer of -2147483648 for this case?

Comment: Semantics: Is b31 the MSB for a signed integer value? Or is it the sign bit, and not a power of two like the other 31 bits?

Comment: @Fe2O3 We are working in two's compliment, so it should be the sign bit

Comment: The result of bit-shifting negative values is not defined by the C standard. Left-shifting is undefined behavior and right-shifting is implementation-defined. I guess this may change with C2x.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Shouldn't the function just return the sign bit for all negative numbers since it would be 1? I'm not sure how I would implement this tho.

Comment: What's "Max ops"? Machine code instructions? On what CPU?

Comment: @Lundin The legal ops are listed on the line above that line.

Comment: @user3386109 That requirement makes no sense then.

Comment: So... looks like you might need to teach your teacher that there's no necessary relation between the number of operators in an expression and the efficiency of your program. For example something like `if(val & (1u << 31))` _does not_ execute a bit shift operation, because `1u << 31` is an integer constant expression calculated at compile-time.

Comment: @Lundin David's answer has 12 ops, and needs 3 more to be complete. And based on [OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75241759/) it seems like you can always perform the task with one less op than the limit. The note added by iBug at the top of that question explains what these problems are really about.

Comment: is the prototype `int SigBitMask(int x)` mandatory? `unsigned int SigBitMask(unsigned int x)` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for referring to the other question and the note adding the assumptions on the result of bit-shifting signed integers. Without those assumptions, I do not think there is a possible solution to this question.

Comment: @chqrlie It not only seems more appropriate, it is the only one making sense without assuming two's complement representation of signed integers (which the standard does not (yet)). However, apparently this prototype is a requirement of the assignment and the necessary assumptions are found in the note added to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75241759/make-a-function-that-returns-1-if-x-y-otherwise-return-0). Both questions do not make sense without those assumptions.

Comment: @Lundin The "max operations" are probably counted in the source code (there is a difference between school and real life).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of your last line because it doesn't do anything.  So your function becomes:

```
int SigBitMask(int x) {
  x |= x >> 1;
  x |= x >> 2;
  x |= x >> 4;
  x |= x >> 8;
  x |= x >> 16;
  return x ^ (x >> 1);
}
```

This works great for non-negative inputs, but for negative inputs, `x` will be -1 when the last line runs, so the last line will give a result of zero.  But that's bad, because we want to return -2147483648 (i.e. 0x80000000) for all negative inputs.

What if we could patch the `return` expression, by using `|` to combine it with another expression that is 0x80000000 when x is -1, and 0 when is x is non-negative?  (We don't care about its values for other negative values of `x`.)  Can you think of such an expression?  I can think of one using only 3 operators, but it involves a little bit of undefined behavior.

Comment: For negative inputs, the value of `x` will be implementation-defined according to C11 paragraph 6.5.7.5.

Comment: For an introductory coding assignment, I think it unlikely that OP is expected to worry about negative values.

Comment: The error message he is getting is from a test case that uses a negative input.

Comment: Yes, that's a good start, the expression looks like `expr << 31`.  Now can you think of an expression that is 1 for `x = -1` and 0 otherwise?  I promise it just uses two of the operators on your list, it is not `x == -1`.

Comment: Hint: what are the bits of -1?

Comment: Nope, remember that right shifting -1 just results in -1 (or maybe it's implementation defined?).  Try a different operator besides right shift for your first step.

Comment: Unfortunately that expression ignores all the bits besides the least significant one, so the answer for -1 is the same as the value for 1, when we wanted them to be different.  You're getting closer.

Comment: You're right that `~` flips all the bits, so what is the value of `~x` in our special case, where `x == -1`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, yeah, I guess you could do `(x >> 31 & 1) << 31`.  That should work, try it!  The expression I was thinking of is different and shorter  but yours is just as good.

Comment: Remember what I said in the answer: "What if we could patch the return expression, by using | to combine it with another expression that is...".  You don't want to replace your whole return expression because then you would not give the right answer for non-negative input.  We are just coming up with another term to combine with the expression you already have.

Comment: I think you didn't read the start of my answer.  Take the exact function I posted and then append `| (x >> 31 & 1) << 31` to the return expression.  It is important for x to be -1 when that last line runs,  instead of 0, for negative inputs.  Go ahead and read all the other sentences in my answer just to be sure.